# Haskell error: Non-exhausive patterns in function

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement a list, which searches for a certain pattern in a Tuple (goes through the list of Tuples, empties this and then writes those in, which match the pattern) in the end the list I entered will be empty and then it writes the matching Tuples in this list.

(The functions used do all work - the mistake is in this part)

```
PatternFinder :: String -> [(String, String)] , [(String, String)]
PatternFinder = n ((b,a) : xs) = 
if PatternFits n a
then do 
 PatternFinder n xs
 (b,a) : xs
else PatternFinder n xs
```

Comment: You can't define functions that start with a capital letter. That is reserved for data constructors. Your indentation will also cause a syntax error. In the future, please paste your actual, compiling code verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the text of your question, it seems like you want a simple filter based on the second term of each pair.

```
patternFinder n = filter (patternFits n . snd)
```

As an illustration of how this works.

```
filter ((==1) . snd) [('a',1),('b',2),('c',1)]
```

returns `[('a',1),('c',1)]`

In Chad Gilberts answer, however, there is no recursion in the then clause:

```
if patternFits n a
then (b,a) : xs
else patternFinder n xs
```

This will return the suffix of the list after the first match. If this is the intended behavior, you could use instead:

```
patternFinder n = dropwhile (not . patternFits n . snd)
```

As an example of this:

```
dropWhile (not . (==2) . snd) [('a',1),('b',2),('c',1)]
```

returns `[('b',2),('c',1)]`

Also, in the text of your question you require that the list you entered will be empty. Note that these functions do nothing to the original list but return new lists.

Comment: Wow this is well explained and I was actually trying to figure out how this works right now - thanks for the good help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not the case of the second argument being the empty list. In order to be exhaustive, you have to handle this pattern:

```hs
patternFinder n []
```

You've also got other syntax errors. Function names must start with a lowercase letter, signatures are separated by `->`, not `,`, and you don't need a `do` statement because you're not in a monad context. It should probably look more like this:

```hs
patternFinder :: String -> [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)]
patternFinder n [] = []
patternFinder n ((b,a) : xs) = 
    if patternFits n a
    then (b,a) : xs
    else patternFinder n xs
```

Comment: I tried that, by adding   " patternFinder n [] = xs" , however I always got variable not in scope...

Comment: Must be a problem, which relates to me first emptying the list and then trying to write in it again, however I don't know how to solve that problem ...

Comment: Ugh, dammit - still learning so I will try to work on that, but if I get those right it should work?

Comment: I've added an example that fixes your syntax errors but I'm curious - did your example actually compile? And if so, what compiler are you using?

Comment: yes it did, I am using geany, is there any other you could recommend?

Comment: Oh and one more thing, isn't do used to execute several patterns (for example here in an if statement) where pattern matching is not possible (or is it)?

Comment: Industry standard is GHC. I've never heard of geany and if it accepts otherwise-invalid Haskell code like you posted, I'd strongly advise against it because there is little community support. I'd recommend [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org) for the easiest platform (it uses GHC but is easiest to get started with)

Comment: `do` is not for pattern matching. It is [syntactic sugar for monad binding functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)

Comment: Thanks for the great help :D